# Why is my UITableView not animating all rows the same, when leaving editing mode?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

This is similar to my previous question, but my previous question was actually somewhat answered, and this is kind of an extension of it.

I have a `UITableView` that I am putting into and out of editing mode. While in editing mode, I display an additional row with the insert icon. All other rows, from my data source, are displayed with a delete icon.

For some reason, the last row from my data source is not animating the same as all the other rows, when leaving editing mode. This looks like some obvious code issue to me, based on the behavior, but I can't seem to fix it. I made an animated GIF to show you what I'm talking about:

[image]

Does anybody know why this might be happening? It's always that last row from my data source. The custom insert row's icon animates out just fine. It's not a ton of code, but it's easiest to view it all at once, so I will link you to the exact code on Github:

https://github.com/ryancole/pound-client/blob/master/pound-client/controllers/ChannelListViewController.m#L100

Comment: What exactly is the issue, I can't tell from that animation how  different the bottom row animation is from all the other rows.

Comment: When the view is taken *out* of editing mode, the 2nd to last row's red circle icon does not slide out, like the rest.

Comment: It looks to me that the issue has to do with a row being added and deleted. I haven't looked at the code yet though.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand. In my `setEditing` function, I'm only adding *or* deleting. What suggests that something is being added *and* deleted? I've seen that mentioned elsewhere, but I still don't understand. My code should only be doing one or the other. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is not with the tableView or any code associated with that. It seems like it is causing because of the pull to refresh view. Unfortunately I don't have the code for that component. I tried your with out the pull to refresh and it is working perfectly. So please remove the pull to refresh and see what is happening.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think the pull to refresh view would have anything to do with that. Regardless, I removed it entirely and the animation is still not matching up. Did you pull down my code, or just make a test project and did what I'm doing, basically? If so, could you put that code online and I will pull it down?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface zViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@end



#import "zViewController.h"

@interface zViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* data;
@end

@implementation zViewController{
    BOOL _editing;
}
@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize table = _table;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _editing = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(editButtonWasPressed:)];
    [self loadRecords];
}

- (void)editButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveButtonWasPressed:)];
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)saveButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(editButtonWasPressed:)];
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    _editing = editing;

    if (editing == YES) {
        [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.data.count -1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.table setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing == NO) {
        [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.data.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self fetchChannels];
}

- (void)fetchChannels {
    [self.table reloadData];
}

-(void) loadRecords{
    self.data = @[@"Record 1", @"Record 2", @"Record 3"];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return (indexPath.row == self.data.count)? UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert : UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _editing? self.data.count + 1 : self.data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.data[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer instead of _just_ posting code?

Comment: This is exactly same as your code. I have all the events that you are handling nothing more than that. I just pasted code from your code and didn't a change much. The only change how it is getting the data. I have fixed amount of data that is not coming from service call.You have it coming from service call. I don't have the pull to refresh. And you have it that is the only difference I see

Answer (score 0):

The animation is correct. You are inserting/deleting last row in `-setEditing:animated:`, so there are two kinds of animations are going on.

Comment: In `setEditing:animated:` I am only inserting *or* deleting the last row.  Which two animations are occurring?

Comment: One is insert/delete, the other is `[UITableViewCell setEditing:animated:]`.

Comment: Do you know how to resolve this issue, though? It sounds like you at least know what's causing it. Do you have any suggestions as to how to get these icons to animate out all the same animation?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue. It is the correct behavior. That said, you can still break the animations into two phases by scheduling the second phase(`setEditing`) immediately after the first phase(insert/delete), either with `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or `dispatch_after`.

Comment: Just to be clear that we're on the same page, you do see that the last "remove icon" does not animate at all, when leaving editing mode, correct? This is not an issue, and is the correct behavior?

Comment: Change `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` to `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` or any other `UITableViewRowAnimation` style you want.

Comment: Does my animated GIF really not make what I'm talking about that clear? I'm not talking about the rows, I'm talking about the icons. Yes, I can get the row to animate in an out, but that does not change the icon animation. Do you see that the icons are not all animating the same?

Comment: Your wording is as fuzzy as your GIF: "For some reason, the last row from my data source is not animating the same as all the other rows, when leaving editing mode." "The custom insert row's icon animates out just fine." I think you should improve both of them for those of us who want to help to understand your problem better.